# Api, Sdk Facebook - obtener información sin login

Tags: facebook

Es posible a através del api o sdk de Facebook obtener si un usuario sigue o le gustas una fan page?

Tengo una una bases de datos de correos electrónicos y números de teléfonos de usuarios de Facebook y deseo saber si solamente con esta información (email, número) existe un Api o se puede construir un Api para saber está información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. No se puede. De hecho, nunca se ha podido.

Antiguamente (hasta antes del escándalo [Cambridge analítica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambridge_Analytica#Esc%C3%A1ndalo_de_Facebook)) si estabas logueado en Facebook podías buscar a tus "amigos" mediante su teléfono o email. Eso llevó a que empresas inescrupulosas adquirieran bases de datos de millones de correos y teléfonos, y mediante un scraper los asociaron a perfiles de facebook, y con ese cruce de bases hicieron además uso con propósitos antiéticos.

Después del escándalo, Facebook ya no permitió hacer esto como usuario, logueado en la plataforma y via web. Sin embargo, a través del API **nunca se pudo**, ni siquiera antes del escándalo.

Me parece que hoy en día, si acaso

1. tu aplicación tuviese login,
2. un usuario se logueara y te otorgara los permisos `pages_admin` y `pages_show_list`,
3. tu aplicación tuviese además la aprobación de Facebook (previa postulación a review) para pedir tales permisos
4. el usuario tuviera rol de admin o moderador de la página

Entonces podrías pegarle al endpoint `feed` de ésta, y a través de ello obtener los posts, y de los posts obtener los comentarios y reacciones, y de éstos obtener el `user_id`. Sin embargo, se trata de `user_id` relacionados específicamente a esa página. La misma persona tiene otro `user_id` cuando interactúa con otra página, **justamente para que no puedas combinar esos ids con bases de datos propias.**

Comment: Gracias por la información